# How can i write Hibernate Criteria

Tags: hibernate, hql, hibernate-mapping, hibernate-criteria

In what we can add restriction to criteria?

For the HQL-1#

```
select activity from EmployeeActivity activity
   join activity.activityStep as step
   where
   activity.currentStep = 1;

Criteria ctr = getSession().createCriteria(EmployeeActivity.class)
   .createCriteria("activityStep")//Where activityStep is the another entity which is joined
   .add(Restrictions.eq("currentStep", 1))
```

But how should i write for the below HQL query? And, what is the best practice.

```
select activity from EmployeeActivity activity
   join activity.activityStep as step
   where
   activity.currentStep = step.stepNumber;
```

Comment: is `activityStep` a reference or a collection? Why is currentStep a number an not a reference to a Step?

Comment: activityStep is just reference to another table, thats why using a simple join. The above query does simple join to two tables EmployeeActivity & ActivityStep using EMPLOYEE_ACTIVITY_ID.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

although i am not sure what the query should do

```
Criteria ctr = getSession().createCriteria(EmployeeActivity.class)
   .createAlias("activityStep", "step")
   .add(Restrictions.propertyEq("currentStep", "step.stepNumber"));
```